# Try...catch vs .catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So I have this user service functions in `service.ts` which includes database stuffs.

```
export const service = {
  async getAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    try {
      const result = await query
      return result
    } catch (e) {
      report.error(e)
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

And `query.ts` file for some reasons, eg: caching, business logic, etc.

```
export const query = {
  async index(): Promise<User[]> {
    try {
      const result = await service.getAll()
      return result
    } catch (e) {
      report.error(e)
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

And another upper layer for `routers` and `resolvers`, because I want to see all routes in one file.

```
export const resolver = {
  Query: {
    users: (): Promise<User[]> => query.index(),
  },

  ...
}
```

Do I need to wrap `try...catch` in all functions? Or can't I just add `.catch` at the very top layer like this:

```
export const resolver = {
  Query: {
    users: (): Promise<User[]> => query.index().catch(e => e),
  },

  ...
}
```

Comment: Don't use throw new Error(e).. Better to bubble you exception up and handle it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to wrap `try...catch` in all functions?

No, you don't, not unless you want to log it at every level for some reason. Just handle it at the top level.

In an `async` function, promise rejections are exceptions (as you know, since you're using `try`/`catch` with them), and exceptions propagate through the `async` call tree until/unless they're caught. Under the covers, `async` functions return promises and reject those promises when a synchronous exception occurs or when a promise the `async` function is `await`ing rejects.

Here's a simple example:

```js
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function outer() {
    // ...
    await delay(10);
    
    console.log("before calling inner");
    await inner();
    console.log("after calling inner (we never get here)");
}

async function inner() {
    // ...
    await delay(10);
    
    console.log("inside inner");
    
    // Something goes wrong
    null.foo();
}

outer()
.catch(e => {
    console.log("Caught error: " + e.message, e.stack);
});
```

---

Just as a side note: If you *do* catch an error because you want to do X before the error propagates and you're going to re-throw the error after you do X, best practice is to re-throw the error you caught, rather than creating a new one. So:

```
} catch (e) {
    // ...do X...
    throw e; // <== Not `throw new Error(e);`
}
```

But only do that if you really need to do X when an error occurs. Most of the time, just leave the `try`/`catch` off entirely.

Comment: thank you for explaining how to correctly rethrow the error.